# maven-enforcer-plugin - Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed

Tags: java, maven, maven-enforcer-plugin

I am working on some legacy project, currently trying to remove maintained parent-pom. All typical maven tasks works (comile, install, test). But during release it is failing on command: `mvn release:prepare release:perform`. And in the console I see:

```
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time:  1.611 s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2023-10-10T20:41:54+02:00
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce (default) on project my-project-plugin: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
[INFO] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce (default) on project my-project-plugin: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed.
```

and when I check above, I can see:

```
[INFO] [WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequirePluginVersions failed with message:
[INFO] Some plugins are missing valid versions:(LATEST RELEASE SNAPSHOT are not allowed )
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin.    The version currently in use is 3.3.0
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin.   The version currently in use is 3.6.0
```

Which does not say anything to me. Any tip or advice what can I check?

Comment: You are using an outdated version of maven-enforcer-plugin (maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1)? Why ? The message tells that you have not defined (pinned) the versions of the used plugin via pluginManagement which you always should with all your plugins

Comment: In `pom.xml` I have configured version: `3.4.1` of maven-enforcer-plugin. Not sure why in console is version: 3.0.0-M1

Comment: That means thre is something wrong in your pom file...without the full pom files I can't even guess....